# How do I make a vb.net multi-threaded WMI query application

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, wmi

I'm a beginner so forgive me if this is a stupid question... I have a list of machines that I then want to pull WMI information for (in this case it's OS info) and then update a ListView in a form. I'm looking for the easiest way to make the following code multi-threaded in an efficient manner perhaps using Task Factory? From what I have read, it would seem that each computer would need to be put into a collection, then each thread would need to update the object in the collection?

Here is my original code:

```
Imports System.Management

Public Class Form1
Public PC As New pc
Public WMI As New WMIConnect
Public i As Integer = 1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    With lv_Inventory
        .Visible = True
        .UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = False
        .View = View.Details
        .Scrollable = True
        .Sort()
        .HideSelection = False
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .GridLines = True
        .AllowColumnReorder = True
        .Columns.Add("Name", 100)
        .Columns.Add("LastBoot", 150)
        .Columns.Add("OS", 125)
        .Columns.Add("Version", 100)
        .Columns.Add("SP", 75)
    End With

    For Each Machine As ListViewItem In lv_Machines.SelectedItems
        lv_Inventory.Items.Add(Machine.Text)
        'Dim PC As New pc
        WMI.WMIConnect(Machine.Text, tb_user.Text, tb_pass.Text)
        PC.Name = Machine.Text
        GetOS()
        lv_Inventory.Items(i - 1).SubItems.Add(PC.LastBootTime)
        lv_Inventory.Items(i - 1).SubItems.Add(PC.OperatingSystem)
        lv_Inventory.Items(i - 1).SubItems.Add(PC.OSVersion)
        lv_Inventory.Items(i - 1).SubItems.Add(PC.ServicePack)
        i += 1
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub GetOS()

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim lastboot As String = Nothing
    Dim m As ManagementObject
    Dim queryCollection As ManagementObjectCollection
    queryCollection = wmi.wmiQuery _
    ("SELECT Caption, Lastbootuptime, version, csdversion, csname, SystemDirectory FROM   Win32_OperatingSystem")

    If queryCollection Is Nothing Then
        ' Me.LostConnection()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each m In queryCollection
        pc.Hostname = UCase(m("csname"))
        pc.LastBootTime = m("LastBootUpTime")
        pc.OSVersion = m("Version")
        pc.ServicePack = m("CSDVersion")
        pc.OperatingSystem = m("Caption")
    Next
End Sub

End Class


Public Class WMIConnect
Public Shared wmiScope As Management.ManagementScope
Public Shared RegScope As Management.ManagementScope

Public Sub WMIConnect(ByVal Machine As String, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Pass As String)
    Dim wmiConnectionOptions As New Management.ConnectionOptions

    With wmiConnectionOptions
        .Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
        .Timeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)
        .Authentication = System.Management.AuthenticationLevel.Packet
        .Username = Username
        .Password = Pass
        .EnablePrivileges = True
    End With

    Try
        Dim wmiScope As New Management.ManagementScope("\\" & _
                   Machine & "\root\cimv2", wmiConnectionOptions)
        wmiScope.Connect()
        Dim RegScope As New Management.ManagementScope("\\" & _
                   Machine & "\root\default:StdRegProv", wmiConnectionOptions)
        RegScope.Connect()
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & e.ToString)
    End Try


End Sub

Public Function wmiQuery(ByVal QueryString As String) As Management.ManagementObjectCollection
    Try
        Dim query As Management.ObjectQuery
        query = New Management.ObjectQuery(QueryString)
        Dim searcher As Management.ManagementObjectSearcher
        searcher = New Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiScope, query)
        Dim queryCollection As Management.ManagementObjectCollection
        queryCollection = searcher.Get()
        Return queryCollection
    Catch
        Dim queryCollection As Management.ManagementObjectCollection = Nothing
        Return queryCollection
    End Try

End Function
End Class


Public Class pc

Public Shared Name As String
Public Hostname As String
Public OperatingSystem As String
Public ServicePack As String
Public OSVersion As String
Public LastBootTime As String

End Class
```

Here is what the updated code in the parallel task looks like:

```
        Parallel.ForEach(lv_Machines.SelectedItems.Cast(Of Object), _
                 Sub(machine)

                     ' ... work with currentElement
                     Try
                         Dim WMI As New wmiConnection
                         Dim PC As New pc
                         Dim i As Integer = 1
                         Dim int As Integer = 1
                         tb_Log.Text += "working on machine " & machine.text & vbCrLf
                         WMI.WMIConnect(machine.Text, tb_user.Text, tb_pass.Text)
                         tb_Log.Text += "WMI connect to machine " & machine.text & vbCrLf
                         PC.Name = machine.Text
                         GetOS(PC, WMI)
                         GetHardware(PC, WMI)
                         GetNetwork(PC, WMI)

                         With lv_Inventory
                             .Items.Add(PC.Name.ToString)
                             With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                                 .Add(PC.LastBootTime.ToString & "")
                                 .Add(PC.OperatingSystem.ToString & "")
                                 .Add(PC.OSVersion.ToString & "")
                                 .Add(PC.ServicePack.ToString & "")
                                 .Add(PC.SerialNumber.ToString & "")
                                 .Add(PC.ChassisType.ToString & "")
                                 .Add(PC.CPU.ToString & "")
                                 .Add(PC.PhysicalMemory.ToString & "")
                                 .Add(PC.Model.ToString & "")
                                 .Add(PC.Manufacturer.ToString & "")
                                 .Add(PC.MacAddress.ToString & "")
                             End With
                         End With

                         tb_Log.Text += "Processing: " & machine.Text & " Thread ID: " & Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId & vbCrLf
                     Catch ex As Exception
                         tb_Log.Text += "Error: " & ex.ToString & vbCrLf
                     End Try

                 End Sub)
```

I think with the new code I may now be battling Thread syncronization issues...The trace logs seem to indicate that the WMI object appears to be getting overwritten by the previous/next task and thus the final info in my list view ends up just having the same result set as the last PC object we created and connected to (hitting a race condition). Do I need to perform a sync lock on the WMI connect and release it after it finishes getting the data? If so then would it much faster than a non-multithreaded for/each as I would need to lock both the WMI object and the PC object? I basically just need a way to take a list of computers and connect to each one of them and get the details in a multi-threaded manner. Here is the output of my trace log:

1. working on machine col-01
2. working on machine col-02
3. WMI connect to machine WI-01
4. getting cpu information... for WI-01
5. getting drive information... for WI-01
6. getting enclosure type. for WI-01
7. Processing: WI-01 Thread ID: 10
8. WMI connect to machine sta-01
9. WMI connect to machine sta-02
10. Getting cpu information... WI-01
11. getting cpu information... WI-01
12. getting drive information... WI-01
13. getting drive information... WI-01
14. getting enclosure type. for WI-01
15. getting enclosure type. for WI-01
16. Processing: sta-01 Thread ID: 9
17. Processing: sta-02 Thread ID: 6

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably the easiest way would be to use Threaded.ForEach .  You can find details here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.100).aspx

That requires .net4 or greater.

Comment: ok so after further digging it appears though the threaded forEach option is not working as expected. My PC object/class which holds the values for each of the machines that are being queried ends up being overwritten each time the ForEach is executed and thus my ListView ends up with only 1 set of data duplicated for however many times the ForEach has run. Based on that I'm thinking I need to create a collection of PC objects (1 for each machine in my list) and then add the data to the properties in my threaded foreach statement for each item in the PC collection? Is that a thread safe way?

Comment: All the variables you use in the ForEach lambda have to be exclusive to that lambda.  Meaning your variables PC, WMI, and i all need to be declared within the lambda.  Additionally, if you are processing the items and adding them to a collection, you should SysLock the collection when adding each item.

Comment: Ok, so I modified my code to put the PC,WMI, and i all into the forEach lambda but it still was showing all of the same info in my list view. I added some trace logging info and found that it appears as though the Foreach executes all of the code in the lamda at different times? I"m guessing it was designed to work this way but the problem then is that my WMI connections end up reporting that they pulled info for a machine but the machine is wrong as that was not the thread that opened that WMI connnection in the first place. Here is what my trace looks like:

Comment: I have added a code snippet to my original post to show what the updated foreach looks like.